# Compiling Java 8 Project into a Java 6 jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

Hello I have a Java 8 Project (Using intellij) and I want to compile it into a jar that will be able to run on JRE of java 6 is it possible ? and if yes how can i make it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Java 8 features you use, [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) can help (no point in copying the entire readme here).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your project compile level to 6 and re-build,if you don't use any Java 8 features.

In intellij, press `F4` on your Project, then on `Project Settings` page, click `Project`, modify `Project language level` to `6 @Override in interfaces`.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: and what do i do in case i use lambdas for spark framework

Comment: You can change lambdas to normal code.Just google it, you can find the result.